# How do I map key combinations (pressing buttons simultaneously, not sequentially) in vim?

Tags: python, vim, keyboard

How do I map key combinations(pressing buttons simultaneously, not sequentially) in vim?
suppose I wanted to map the command `:!python % <ENTER>` to pressing the keys `j` and `k` together?

I tried `:map j+k :!python % <ENTER>`, `:map j-k :!python % <ENTER>` and `:map <j-k> :!python % <ENTER>` but this doesn't work.

Also, which button combinations would you recommend mapping? (please not `F1`, `F2`, ... no combination with `ctrl` or `shift`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If using scripts is acceptable for you, then there is [arpeggio](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425) script which should suit your needs.

Comment: Only if there is no other way.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way.