# How do I map Alt Gr key combinations in vim?

Tags: python, vim, keyboard

Suppose I wanted to map the command `:!python % <ENTER>` to pressing the keys `Alt Gr` and `j` together?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I map key combinations (pressing buttons simultaneously, not sequentially) in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751270/how-do-i-map-key-combinations-pressing-buttons-simultaneously-not-sequentially)

Comment: What is your terminal type (TERM variable)? A few things can be done in XTERM with Function Keys and all 8 combinations of Shift/Ctrl/Alt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AltGr is interpreted by your keyboard driver, so Vim isn't aware of it in terms of a modifier key. However, there are [two ways](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim#1d._Entering_literal_characters_.26_terminal_codes) getting the key code for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>. In insert mode:

1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> (shows the literal character code)
2. hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> and then release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> (shows the terminal code)

The result depends on your keyboard layout. If you just get `j` then you're out of luck.

Comment: I have Ctrl-v mapped to paste. What's the command that Ctrl-v is mapped to by default?

Comment: Answering my own question-in-the-comments: I can use Ctrl-Q from insert mode to access whatever-it-is that Ctrl-v does by default in item 1. from Stefan's answer (literal character code.) I can't get showing the terminal code to work (but I'm sure it works fine if you haven't remapped Ctrl-v)

Answer (score 6):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, many key combinations cannot be used, even in GVIM. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

A basic rule is: If the key combination yields a visible character in command-line mode, it can be mapped. But in particular for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, it may be the same mapping as <kbd>Alt</kbd>, depending on what your OS returns when it's combined with the other key.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.