# Change inside brackets not working in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to change the text inside brackets with `ci{` but there is nothing happening at all.
When I'm trying to do this with `ci"` it works fine. When being in insert mode, I can type `(`,`{`,`[`, just as usual, and even the jumping between paragraphs with `{` or `}` just works as expected. It seems like it's just the `ci{` commands that don't work.

For example I have the following sentence in the document, with | being the cursor and in normal-mode:

> This| is a "Test" {or isn't it}.

`ci{` results in still being normal-mode

> This| is a "Test" {or isn't it}.

But `ci"` results in with being in insert-mode

> This is a "|" {or isn't it}.

I'm using manjaro, with i3, and urxvt.

I've found out that this key is interpreted by the keyboard driver and therefore is not understood by vim from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751575/how-do-i-map-alt-gr-key-combinations-in-vim) post.

Is there a workaround or a solution to this?

Comment: Can we have a concrete example, with the position of the cursor when you do `ci{` and `ci"`? Also, describe your environment: OS? terminal or GUI? If terminal, what terminal emulator? What shell? What `$TERM`? What Vim (full output of `$ vim --version`)? Etc.

Comment: ci{ isn't changing the cursors position at all. It just stays there and a bell would ring. 
I'm adding one.

Comment: `i{` can't work in this case because the cursor is not *between* braces. Same for `i(`, `i[`, and others. It has nothing to do with your keyboard driver. The behaviour of `i"` and `i'` is an exception. If you want normal text objects to work like abnormal ones there are various snippets and plugins floating around the web.

Comment: @romainl, can you point any reference for such exception on `ci"`?

Comment: You can leave out the version, it would have been relevant when you asked the question but it's irrelevant, now.

Comment: @romainl thank you! Why not make it an answer, I'd be happy to give you the points :)

Comment: I already did, several years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650788/why-ci-and-ci-ci-behave-differently/14651443#14651443

Comment: I searched the forum and internet lol, but didnt' find that post. Thanks

Comment: In some means yes. There is a solution described there.